# \endlist \ifx \enit@series \relax \else \if

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

ı get that error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\enit@endenumerate ->\enit@after 
                                 \endlist \ifx \enit@series \relax \else \if...
l.167 \end{enumerate}
```

---

```
 %--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm,right=2cm,top=3cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newtheorem{llemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{prop}[llemma]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{pf}[llemma]{Proof}
\newtheorem{exmp}[llemma]{Example}
\newtheorem{ttheorem}[llemma]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{ccorollary}[llemma]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{defn}[llemma]{Definition}
\newtheorem{rem}[llemma]{Remark}
\newtheorem{cconjecture}[llemma]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{nnote}[llemma]{Note}
\newtheorem{key}[llemma]{Keyword}
\newtheorem{ack}[llemma]{Acknowledgement}
\newtheorem{pro}[llemma]{Property}
\newtheorem{result}[llemma]{Result}
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item The given operators based on archimedean  norms are introduced to propose
a new decision making method for solving an MADM-problems with trapezoidal fuzzy multi numbers.
    \item  The main aim is to develop ATS-TFMWA operator and
ATS-TFMWG operator for a MADM-problems with trapezoidal fuzzy multi
numbers.
    \item A method is constructed under MADM-problems with trapezoidal fuzzy multi numbers.
    \item An example  for application is given to show the effectiveness and advantage of the introduced method.
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  You can highlight your code and click `{}` to make it properly formatted.  But please trim this down to a minimal example, and add some text about what you're trying to do.

Comment: do not do `\usepackage{enumitem} \usepackage{enumerate} ` just use the first. also as previously noted do not do `\usepackage{epsfig} `

Comment: please fix your example so it does not use all the unrelated packages, and does make the error you ask about

Comment: Problem solved? If yes, please consider accepting the provided answer.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

A more reasonable example would be

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item x
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Which produces

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\enit@endenumerate ->\enit@after 
                                 \endlist \ifx \enit@series \relax \else \if...
l.10 \end{enumerate}
                    
?
```

Simply delete

```
\usepackage{enumerate}
```

The two packages both redefine `\enumerate` you can not make both work at the same time. `enumitem` can do everything `enumerate` can do so you never need `\usepackage{enumerate}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item x
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```